# PHP - preg_match_all Same Group, Different Pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
<?php
    $str = '123.456.789.987,654,321,';

    // preg_match_all('((?<grp1>\d{3})\.|(?<grp2>\d{3})\,)', $str, $matches);
    preg_match_all('((?<grp1>\d{3})\.|(?<grp1>\d{3})\,)', $str, $matches);

    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Based on code above, I want to get all the string as an group array called `grp1`, but it always become error `PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same name at offset ...`. If I change one of the group name to `grp2` it works well.

**Is it possible to using 1 group name instead of different group name in preg_match_all?**

---

**Update**

There is a reason why I cannot using something like this `/(?<grp1>\d{3})[.,]/`, here is an example to clear the problem:

```
<?php
    $str = '
        src="img1.png"
        src="img2.jpg"
        url(img3.png)
        url(img4.jpg)
    ';

    preg_match_all('/src=\"(?<img1>(\w+)(.png|.jpg))\"|url\((?<img2>(\w+)(.png|.jpg))\)/', $str, $matches);

    print_r($matches);
?>
```

I want to take all the `img1.png`, `img2.jpg`, `img3.png` and `img4.jpg` into array group named `img` something like this:

```
[img] => Array
    (
        [0] => img1.png
        [1] => img2.jpg
        [2] => img3.png
        [3] => img4.jpg
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a regex in PHP needs to be wrapped in boundaries like `/` or `#` etc.

Then your regex doesn't need to be this complex. Same can be simplified using this regex:

```
/(?<grp1>\d{3})[.,]/
```

**Full Code:**

```
$str = '123.456.789.987,654,321,';
preg_match_all('/(?<grp1>\d{3})[.,]/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches['grp1']);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 456
    [2] => 789
    [3] => 987
    [4] => 654
    [5] => 321
)
```

**UPDATE:** As per your updated question:

```
$str = '
        src="img1.png"
        src="img2.jpg"
        url(img3.png)
        url(img4.jpg)
    ';
preg_match_all('/(?<=src="|url\()(?<img>[^")]+)/i', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches['img']);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => img1.png
    [1] => img2.jpg
    [2] => img3.png
    [3] => img4.jpg
)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, I think I miss something with my explanation. Please see my updated question above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, but can you explained to me what the regex do? I'm new for this thing.

Comment: Sure. `(?<=src="|url\()` is a positive lookbehind that makes sure to match `next part` if it is preceded by `src="` or `url(`. Next part is to match 1 or more characters until `"` or `)` is found.

Comment: And what's the `i` do in the end?

Comment: i is for ignore case to src and SRC will both be matched.